# com.databricks.sql.cloudfiles.errors.CloudFilesException: Failed to create an Event Grid subscription

Tags: azure, azure-databricks, azure-rbac

I'm trying to use an autoloader to pick up files from a container in ADLS and store them as delta files in a delta table explicitly defined at an external location in a different container within the same storage account called "Bronze". When i try to write the stream with Trigger = Once option, i get an error "
com.databricks.sql.cloudfiles.errors.CloudFilesException: Failed to create an Event Grid subscription.Please make sure that your service principal has 'write' permissions

The exact Error is as follows :

> {
> "error" : {
> "code" : "LinkedAuthorizationFailed",
> "message" : "The client '910adb4f-a9dd-4666-ace1-xxxxxxxxxx' with object id '910adb4f-a9dd-4666-ace1-xxxxxxxxxx' has permission to perform action 'Microsoft.EventGrid/eventSubscriptions/write' on scope '/subscriptions/485bf1a4-b8c5-48af-ba04-xxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/StocksDev/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/stockpricesdev/providers/Microsoft.EventGrid/eventSubscriptions/databricks-query-8030d5e2-7058-4cfd-aa7f-b20867633d45-source-0'; however, it does not have permission to perform action(s) 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/write' on the linked scope(s) '/subscriptions/485bf1a4-b8c5-48af-ba04-xxxxxxxxxx/resourcegroups/StocksDev/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/stockpricesdev' (respectively) or the linked scope(s) are invalid."
> }
> }

I have now double checked permissions for the service principal and its according to docs:

1. Storage blob data contributor  on  storage account -  stockpricesdev
2. Storage Queue Data contributor (I'm using the latest runtime >  8.0 without   connection string so i guess i have added it just incase although not required)
3. EventGrid EventSubscription Contributor on the resource group  -  StockDev

I can also see the inherited role assignments within scopes. I'm not sure why this is happening as a contributor role would be sufficient to perform write action

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error occurred as the **roles** you are currently using (*Storage Blob Data Contributor*) does not have **Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/write** permission, which is required to create Event Grid subscription.

To resolve the error, you need to assign either **Contributor** or **Storage Account Contributor** role to the service principal under your storage account.

*Go to Azure Portal -> Storage Accounts -> Select your Storage account -> Access control (IAM) -> Add role assignment -> Contributor*

[image]

For your storage account, you require:

- **Contributor** access, which is necessary for configuring resources within the storage account, like queues and event subscriptions.
- **Storage Queue Data Contributor** access, needed for executing queue operations like message retrieval and deletion.

Within the resource group:

- **EventGrid EventSubscription Contributor** access, utilized for managing event grid subscription operations.

**Reference:**
[Required permissions for configuring file notification - Azure Databricks | Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/ingestion/auto-loader/file-notification-mode#--required-permissions-for-configuring-file-notification-for-adls-gen2-and-azure-blob-storage)